# Efficiently estimating latency quantiles of a distributed system

Tags: algorithms, distributed-systems, statistics

I'm building a load test harness for a distributed system. Currently I'm using the "[Cormode, Korn, Muthukrishnan, and Srivastava](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~muthu/bquant.pdf)" method to estimate latency quantiles of system responses.

I'm now testing systems larger than can be adequately stressed using a single load generator. I'm looking for a method similar to the one cited above that can be extended to a cluster of load generators.

I would like to measure the latency quantiles of responses to the cluster as a whole, and to individual nodes in the cluster without recording/streaming the latency of every event in the system to a central node.

Does such a method exist? If so, are there any public implementations?